# php-fpm ignores error_log when daemonize = no

Tags: logging, php, syslog, rsyslog

Background: I use PHP-FPM inside a Docker container. I set `daemonize = no` in php-fpm.conf so the Docker container itself can be run as daemon.

```
When ..
daemonize = no
error_log = syslog -> is ignored
```

Is there any way, to not ignore `error_log` in this case?

Comment: (Presumably) fixed by https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64915